# Why are the backgrounde/surroundings of intro templates not working?

Tags: rendering, shaders

[image]I tested a few intro templates and with all of them I have the same problem: I can change the text and the animation of it and additional elements are working fine but the background/surrounding is not rendered in the way the example shows(please check the two uploaded images). While the example has a black background with mist, particles, etc. my export shows the naked viewport. As already mentioned I have this problem with several intros tested. What's wrong?[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isQ2b.png)Thanks for your help!

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: are the templates 2.8 ready?

Comment: appearently not - I just tried it with 2.79 it's working there, thanks for the hint